# Spark count() taking long to run

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to do some calculations on PySpark. To begin with, I was just doing a row count on the data, which is already divided in several partitions (after running a query with sqoop).

For the first try, I had 25 partitions for the data, and running the calculations on 5 executors, with 3 cores each, and 15G of memory per executor. Also, I have around 2GB of data (92M lines more or less).

However, with these settings, a simple `sc.textFile()` followed by a `count()` was taking over 3 minutes to run, which seemed a bit excessive. So I did some looking up, and changed some of the settings, testing several combinations.

Right now I'm working with 10 executors, 5 cores, 20GB memory, and 150 partitions. Which seems like overkill to me, but is what gave me the best performance, finishing everything after 40 seconds. But it still seems like, for the amount of resources I'm dedicating to this, and the amount of data I have, it should be faster...

I also tried using a `cache()` after the `sc.textFile()`, to see if it would improve the performance (since, I told myself, reading the files could be the cause behind the slow performance), but it actually *slowed things down*, and some executors even fail when I do `cache()`, with the following message:

`Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 22.4 GB of 22 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`

Now, I also really wanted to understand where these 22.4GB are coming from, considering my files sum 2GB of data (unless sqoop does some sort of compacting which is undone when the data is loaded and which I'm unaware of? At this point I'm just grasping)

Is there anything else I can do to try and improve performance? Or some form of diagnostic I can run to better pinpoint the cause of the problem?

EDIT:

As requested, the input files are .deflated files generated by sqoop after running a query (in other words, the content as it is would be gibberish to us). The most important detail about the input is that, it has around 92M lines in all, each line with 204 columns, and really sparse. When it is read at the beginning, however, it is read as a string, not directly as an array of 204 values. An example would be:

```
u'20,200,0,1,0,1,0,0,36.228189024369268,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,18.0,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.333333,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.333333,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.333333,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0,0,22,0,0,0'
```

As for the code, there really isn't much to it, it's literally just reading the files, and counting it:

```
t = sc.textFile("/user/bc/input/proj1/train")#.cache()
t.count()
```

Where `/user/bc/input/proj1/train` is the directory where all 150 .deflate files are (so, all 150 partitions).

UPDATE:

Also, for some reason, rerunning the code with a `cache()` today worked without giving me a memory error. It seems like .deflate really does compress the files, as the UI tells me that 73% of the RDD has been cached, with 5.2GB in memory. Still, it is quite far from the 22.4GB from yesterday.
Nonetheless, running a count with the cached RDD still gives me worst results than before (52 seconds).

UPDATE2:

So, I still couldn't fix this problem, but there are some more details I can give... Dunno how much they'll help though, but anyway, it's worth a try:

- Changed (again) the configuration. Right now using 8 executors, 4 cores each, 20GB executor memory, 5GB driver memory. Dataset is divided into 32 partitions (so, one per core). I decided to bring down the number of executors since it's a shared cluster, and I was basically taking all the resources for myself lol, so, yeah.
- Reduced the skew in the partitions. So, as of now, I have around 80MB in each file. This helped the tasks to run a tiny bit faster (the skew was really not that big), but all in all still quite slow.
- By looking at the stage information in the Spark UI, all the times indicated (Scheduler Delay, Deserialization Time, GC Time, Result Serialization Time, Getting Result Time) seem correct. Deserialization is around 0.5s for almost all tasks, and GC takes around 0.3s with a few exceptions (one or two tasks that take 1s for GC). All the others are of the order of miliseconds or less.
- The only time that takes really long is "Duration" (median of 35s, max of 1min), which, if I interpreted correctly, means Spark is taking long to perform the count itself, not so much to manage the information being passed around, deserialize it, etc.

I'm really running out of ideas of what could be the cause of this slowness, since I tried quite a few different configurations, and nothing seems to work... Maybe it's something to do with the cluster itself, and not necessarily Spark? Any suggestions and/or demands for further clarifications are extremely welcome :-)

Comment: Hi Berne, as a general advice I'd propose to use the Spark UI for digging deeper into the issue. For instance you could find out there the concrete tasks which takes that long within the event timeline or the DAG (graph). Also you could verify the amount of partitions, used memory etc.

Comment: @AydinK. yes, I'm using the pyspark-shell UI, but it hasn't been helping me find the problem... In fact, after looking at the information in the Spark UI, I leave with more questions than answers (especially when it comes to the memory usage, which just seems really bizarre to me)

Comment: Ok. Just to be sure, with Spark UI I mean the web UI which is started per default on port 4040. You as well, right?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: ok. maybe it helps if you include excerpts of your code (sample input file and relevant parts of the sc.textFile and count stuff) in your request.

Comment: @AydinK. added what you asked, and also tried rerunning the code today, so also put in a small update